# Is it more efficient to subtract a value from a date or use DATEADD with a negative value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure that I need to make more efficient. It currently looks like

```
delete_more:
    DELETE TOP(500)
    FROM [dbo].[Foo]
    WHERE [DateCreated] < DATEADD(DAY, -1 * @MaxAgeInDays, GETDATE())

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
        GOTO delete_more
```

The first step was to extract some variables

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @EarliestDate DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, -1 * @MaxAgeInDays, @Now)

delete_more:
    DELETE TOP(500)
    FROM [dbo].[Foo]
    WHERE [DateCreated] < @EarliestDate

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
        GOTO delete_more
```

But then I thought that perhaps it might be faster if I change `@EarliestDate` to

```
DECLARE @EarliestDate DATETIME = @Now - @MaxAgeInDays
```

Which one would be faster or more clear to both the database, and a dba?

Comment: By the way, your statements are missing statement terminators `;`

Answer (score 3):

The difference, if any, in performance should be so small that it wouldn't be measurable. The calculation is done either way just once. Deleting thousands of rows will surely need far more time to execute than a single calculation.

Having said that, I'd choose the version with the `DATEADD()` as adding a date with an integer doesn't look nice or elegant. OK, it may look a bit like a cool "hack" but it's not best practice and is relying on the internal representation of date/datetime types.

See Aaron Bertrand's blog: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations), where he explains how this kind of code works ok with `DATE` or `DATETIME` but will break your queries when someone changes the type of the column/variable to `DATETIME2`.

Comment: Another difference will be in how the parameter is sniffed. The local variable will result in a non-histogram estimate (2nd version).